# Inserting none or 0 value to every 30 index positions in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists that comes from csv data. I need to add an empty row after every 30 rows. I am not sure why, but my code inserts an empty row only for the first 282534 rows, but after it stops inserting empty rows. In total I have 291593 rows of data and I need to insert an empty row after every 30th row. Here is my code and list:

```
list1=[df['Date'].tolist(),df['ticker'].tolist(), df['cf'].tolist()]
n=30
for l in list1:
    for i in range (n, len(l)+n, n+1):
        l.insert ( i, None)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Two notes: you're a bit unclear that what you actually mean is insert a `None` at every 30th *column* in your inner list, not every *row* in of your outer list. This is important because you're complicating your question by including the outer list at all. Secondly, it seems that insertion-in-place is important to you - otherwise the `insert` function makes your life a bit more complicated than it needs to be. If you're attempting to avoid a copy action, you should be sure to include that aspect in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your inner for loop is doing, but you can insert a new list element every n elements by doing something like this:

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
interval = 2

lx = list()

for idx in range(len(ls)):
  lx.append(ls[idx])
  if idx % interval:
    lx.append(None)


print(lx)
```

In your case, `ls` would be your input list, and `interval` is the interval at which you'd like to add a break. Setting that to `30` would add a break every 30 rows. Note that I inserted `None`, but you'd want to insert whatever an 'empty' row is in your application.

Another way to go about this is to simply calculate where your interval break indexes will fall and insert them.

```
span = 30  # We want a break every 30 items    
count = len(ls) // span  # Total breaks we will add
# A break index at the end of every span interval (i + 1)
# with offset i for to account for previous breaks
idxs = ( ((i + 1) * span) + i for i in range(count) )
[ls.insert(idx, None) for idx in idxs]
```

The last two lines could be combined, but that would make it a bit clunky to read. Note that `idxs` is actually a generator, which means it won't perform the calculation until it is consumed in the last lines list comprehension. That means there will be no memory allocation - avoiding issues that might arise from very large lists.

Comment: I found my mistake, len increases as i insert a new value after every 30th value. So the stop values is len(l)+ len(l)//n

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. The stop value is no longer `len(l)` as `l` length in `list1` increases as we are inserting new rows. Then the stop values becomes `len(l)+ len(l)//n`.

```
n=30
for l in list1:
    for i in range (n, len(l)+ len(l)//n, n+1):
        l.insert ( i, None)
```